# Запуск нового браузера для каждого теста из набора

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

Есть набор автотестов. Когда запускаю в ручную по одному каждый проходит отлично, а когда запускаю что бы все тесты выполнялись по порядку, то проходит только один тест(первый). Как сделать что бы на каждый тест по новому открывался браузер, тест выполнялся и браузер закрывался?

Здесь инициализация браузера

```
 public class TestBase
    {
        protected IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }
      
        public TestBase()
        {
            //var browser = TestContext.Parameters.Get("browser");
            var browser = "Chrome";

            if (!Enum.TryParse(browser, out BrowserType browserType))
            {
                throw new Exception("Browser parameter is not valid");
            }

            var driverFactory = new BrowserFactory();
            Driver = driverFactory.GetDriver(browserType);           
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            Driver.Quit();
        }       
    }
```

Тут сами тесты

```
[TestFixture]
    public class EmailTest : TestBase
    {
        private MainPage _mainPage;
        private EmailPage _emailPage;
        private LoginPage _loginPage;
        private InfoFromJsonFile _jsonFile;
        private TestData _testData;

        public EmailTest()
        {
            _mainPage = new MainPage(Driver);
            _emailPage = new EmailPage(Driver);
            _loginPage = new LoginPage(Driver);
            _jsonFile = new InfoFromJsonFile();
            _testData = _jsonFile.GetTestData();
        }

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {            
            Driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
            Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(_testData.YandexUrl);
        }

        [Test]
        public void OpenEmail_CheckUserName()
        {
            _mainPage.ClickEmailLoginButton();
            _loginPage.LoginInput(_testData.ValidLogin);
            _loginPage.ClickLoginButton();
            _loginPage.PasswordInput(_testData.ValidPassword);
            _loginPage.ClickLoginButton();
            var userName = _emailPage.GetUserName();
            Assert.AreEqual(_testData.ValidLogin, userName);
        }

        [Test]
        public void QuitFromEmailAccount()
        {
            _mainPage.ClickEmailLoginButton();
            _loginPage.LoginInput(_testData.ValidLogin);
            _loginPage.ClickLoginButton();
            _loginPage.PasswordInput(_testData.ValidPassword);
            _loginPage.ClickLoginButton();
            var emailPageUrl = Driver.Url;
            _emailPage.LogOut();
            var currentUrl = Driver.Url;
            Assert.AreNotEqual(emailPageUrl, currentUrl);
        }
```

Вот так такой результат запуска набора тестов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст ошибки

```
  Message: 
    OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:54653/session//timeouts. The status of the exception was UnknownError, and the message was: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
      ----> System.Net.WebException : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
      ----> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
      ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
    TearDown : OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:54653/session//window/handles. The status of the exception was UnknownError, and the message was: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
      ----> System.Net.WebException : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
      ----> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
      ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Comment: А что пишет в исключении?

Comment: Возможно это поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028926/run-selenium-tests-in-multiple-browsers-one-after-another-from-c-sharp-nunit

Comment: @SmorcIRL добавил в описание.

Comment: `Driver = driverFactory.GetDriver(browserType);`  - вызывайте это в `SetUp`, а не в конструкторе

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Как то не помогает этот вариант.

Comment: @ПавелПанасюк я лишь ответил на вопрос `Как сделать что бы на каждый тест по новому открывался браузер, тест выполнялся и браузер закрывался?`. А так, скорее всего, проблема в том, что у вас url какой-то странный с двумя слешами, судя по ошибке: `URL http://localhost:54653/session//timeouts`

Comment: [Cсылка](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8030) - актуальный issue в гитхабе по вашей проблеме. Но я все же склоняюсь к тому, что урл неправильный подставляется

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте попробовал изолировал каждый тест, чтобы они не использовали общие переменные. Создайте два простых изолированных теста без общей логики - и попробуйте запустить

Comment: @AndreiKhotko В таком случае все работает.

Comment: @ПавелПанасюк значит, проблема кроется в том, что вы не можете по окончании теста вернуть состояние страниц либо драйвера в исходное состояние для следующего теста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил но не открытием нового браузера. Перед стартом каждого теста, делаю очистку Cookes и открываю новую вкладку. Таким образом при каждом новом логине получаю пустой браузер.